# Google ads React native

Tags: react-native, admob, google-ads-api

i started working on existing react native projet, that have Google ads which is already working on the playStore.

However,is not working on dev environment, is this is normal ? Does the Google ads works only after uploading the app on  the store ?

Answer (score 0):

i confirm that real ads working on release apk not on debug apk.
i have it succesuflly working on the release version of my app. :D